# EDMX or not EDMX any more?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm bit confused: with all the evolutions of EF i'm not sure where i'm now.

*Is EDMX a choice of the past and should be used any more ?
*If so what is the best choice ?
*I hate edmx, can i upgrade to code first ?

It is not clear what all this EF versions are to me

Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a lot of apps you can start using Code First if you want to. The one big thing Code First doesn't support yet is mapping to stored procedures. (You can still call stored procedures, but you can't map entity CRUD operations to them.)

That being said, doing Database First with an EDMX is still absolutely supported and a fine choice, especially you like using the EF designer.

EF 4.1 and above fully support both Code First and Database First.

Personally, I would almost always choose Code First, even with an existing database, because I'm a code-centric person and would rather keep all my mappings in code where I can easily refactor, manage in source control, split into multiple files, etc. For me, it's much easier and nicer to deal with code artifacts than monolithic XML documents.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should evaluate your Entity Framework usage:

1) EDMX is a totally valid option specifically if you have an **existing Database** and want to generate your entities based on your database schema. One of my favorite benefits to this can be rapid data layer development with low risk. Also mapping stored procedure results to classes is always nice when you have complex existing stored procedures to work with.

**OR**

2) Code First is a totally valid option specifically if you want to create you database based an object oriented data model. With code first its easy to make big refactors that you don't always think of till implementation time. Source control is more common with code and shelving/rolling back are beautiful features.

**TL;DR version :**
They are both totally viable options. Neither are outdated ;nor shall they be any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

We had performance consideration in warm up **EF Code First**. EF Code First take some minutes to start, because we have thousand Entity. so this bottleneck enforced us to Use EDMX, and used [Interactive Pregenerated](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFInteractiveViews) to Create EDMX from Code First in First Run after entity Model changed, and at Other First Run warm up time considerably lowered.

but story not end at that. after doing that we saw in Development area we have many change in Entity Model, so after each change EDMX File should be recreated(update) very often. so we decide to Create EDMX Programatically and Optimize that creation for our Entity Models.